# how can i preg_match a xml declaration using php?

Tags: php, regex, xml, svg, preg-match

I am making a svg uploader service. I want my clients able to upload svg files and the uploaded svg's are then displayed in their personal space.

Two types of svg are usually uploaded :

- clean ones, the file's root element is already `<svg>`, no need to sanitize.
- dirty ones, they are generated from softwares and contain extra headers.

I want to make a special treatment for the latter. removing the extra headers.

The dirty ones' first line is most of time a xml declaration. my question is how can i `preg_match` a xml declaration ?

at this moment, the file is contained in a variable `$file`.

I tried `preg_match('/<\?xml/', $file)` but this doesn't even seem to work.

Comment: SVG is an XML document - why not use XML parser?

Comment: @AleksG good point, however at this time my clients are only using illustrator. If the document contains xml headers, i know i only have to remove the three first lines. nothing too big as to use xml parsers.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags. For the cleanup also see https://github.com/svg/svgo.